# Force parLapply to do jobs in order

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a sequence of jobs that I would like to parallelize as close to in order as possible (I know that some nodes will complete before others).

My current script looks like:

```
library(parallel)

cl <- makeCluster(12)

iseq <- seq(1, 10000, 1)

results <- unlist(parLapply(cl, iseq, function(y){
    write(y, "progress.txt", append=T)
}
))

stopCluster(cl)
```

The values in progress.txt are wildly out of order. 1, 826, 2, 3, 827 and so on.

Comment: the easiest way to do this might be to sort the output rather than play with the parallel calls

Comment: I appreciate that idea, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `clusterApply`, then your results won't be *as* wildly out of order:

```
results <- unlist(clusterApply(cl, iseq, function(y){
    write(y, "progress.txt", append=T)
}
))
```

`parLapply` assigns the tasks to the workers in chunks, so in your case, the first task assigned to one of your workers is task 826. `clusterApply` uses round-robin scheduling, so it can't get too badly out of order.